# General form of an n-th order homogenous PDE of two variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-forms

Question: Is there a general form for a homogenous PDE of two variables?

In the text I am using,  a homogenous PDE:

> Has derivatives all of the same order. (1)

Another source which defines a homogenous PDE the same way: https://youtu.be/vxZUqN8SrhE?t=263

However, other texts state that a homogenous DE simply can be written as L(u)=0

[In this picture, clearly, not all derivatives are of the same order, which breaks (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mVOm.png)
(Taken from this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X10002581))

To add to the confusion, this [site](https://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/sryedida/public_html/caimna/pde/first/partial.html) claims:

> If all the terms of a PDE contains the dependent variable or its partial derivatives then such a PDE is called non-homogeneous partial differential equation

TLDR; What exactly is a homogenous PDE of two variables in its most general form?

Comment: I have no clue, as I suspect many other users as well, as to what exactly the question is here.

Comment: please explain your question clearly. Are you asking if $order(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=order(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$ ?

Comment: My apologies @Klangen. Added a question right at the top. I simply want to know what it means for a PDE to be homogenous

Comment: @KumarNilesh I am asking for the definition of an homogenous ODE. Definition (1) conflicts with others, leading to my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general: *A linear differential equation is homogeneous if it is a homogeneous linear equation in the unknown function and its derivatives. It follows that, if $\phi (x)$ is a solution, so is $c\phi (x)$, for any (non-zero) constant $c$.* And this is true for homogeneous partial differential equation as well.

And as in your link, it's clearly mentioned : *Order of a PDE: The order of the highest derivative term in the equation is called the order of the PDE.*

I think the only reason for the confusion is through the video in your question which says the order of every term in the equation should be equal, which is not true in general for the homogeneous partial differential equation.

you can check other examples online also, So far from my understanding I can say that except for that video rest two sources are correct.

---

**Some Trusted Source:**

[Science direct article, check examples given there](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1878029611008930)

[Hindawi Journal](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/2012/609862/)

[Homogeneous hear equation from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Homogeneous_heat_equation)

[notes from ucsb pg-2](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~grigoryan/124A.pdf)

[Wikiversity](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equations#Homogeneous_PDEs)

[IIT gauhati course notes:](http://www.iitg.ac.in/kartha/CE601-14/Lectures/CE601NumMethLecture31.pdf)

Comment: There are other sources which added to the confusion. 

The first source was this book: https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Ordinary_and_Partial_Differential_Equati.html?id=vaorDAAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y

Second source was the video linked above

Here is another video which claims the same thing : https://youtu.be/XB0Ty2aAWNk?t=142

Yet another (this one is in Hindi) : https://youtu.be/EYK4jmDzrOU?t=107

Finally I had found another source on nptel.ac.in from IIT which also claims that all orders must be equal.

I wonder why so many sources from India are incorrect?

Comment: I will accept your answer if you can provide a source which defines a homogenous ODE as such. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SamarthTripathi I have given some source which defines homogeneous PDE as defined in my answer.

Comment: @SamarthTripathi I don't know why but many Indian lectures on youtube are considering term homogeneous associated with degrees. But in general in simple term any equation is homogenous means the constant term to be 0. I want to know when you'll call a polynomial equation a homogeneous equation?